# Why are non-overlapping intervals equals open set needed in proof that closed sets are measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

I read the proof that all closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are measurable (Lebesgue). The proof states that given a closed bounded set $F$, we can always find an open set $G$ s.t. $F \subseteq G$. Afterwards, to prove that for all $\epsilon > 0$, we have $G \setminus F < \epsilon$, we can approximate $G \setminus F$ using a countable union of non-overlapping intervals $\bigcup I_k$ whose additive measure $\sum m(I_k) < \epsilon$.

But am just wondering, why couldn't we also use (as a proof) the countable union of certain non-overlapping intervals $\bigcup I_k$ to approximate $F$ directly? Since we have here Lebesgue measurable intervals $I_k$, we could construct $I_k$ such that we'll have its countable union $\bigcup I_k=F$. Wouldn't this show that $F$ is also measurable?

P.S. > or is it because the theorem states "all closed sets", we can also have some infinite closed sets s.t. the countable union of closed intervals leads to an open (not closed) set at infinity ?

Comment: What happens to $I_k$ 's when $F=\mathbb R^{n}$?

Comment: "we could construct $I_k$ such that we'll have its countable union $\bigcup I_k=F$." Nope. If $\bigcup I_k=F$ then $F$ is _open_...